# Best way to correct bundle ID

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, app-store-connect

I just realized that something is not working because the case doesn't match in my bundle IDs between iTunes connect and my app in Xcode.

I've run into problems before with case mismatch, so I want to get a consensus on how to fix this problem before I try anything.

The iTunes connect version has an all lower case bundle ID. My project in Xcode has lower case for the revers domain name part but a capital letter for the first letter of the last word.

What's the best way to fix this without creating more problems?

Comment: Do you have a preference for which one is correct?

Comment: No preference. I'm inclined to change info.plist ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} to a hard coded value. But maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply hardcode the bundle ID to a string that matches the Bundle ID in iTunes Connect, rather than using the `${PRODUCT_NAME}` variable. That way, even if you were to change the app name, the bundle ID will always match.

Comment: ROFL - I tried accepting the answer and it said, "You can accept the answer in 0 seconds". Looks like a rounding issue there. In any case, this was simple and worked like a charm.

Comment: As an aside, once you submit an app to the app store, you never want to change the bundle ID (as that makes it a different application)  So if you've submitted the app already, this is really the only solution.

Comment: Right. I knew that, but were that the situation, the bundle ids would already have matched or the app wouldn't have been able to be submitted. Good point, though.